# Resize ctypes array

Tags: python, ctypes

I'd like to resize a ctypes array. As you can see, ctypes.resize doesn't work like it could. I can write a function to resize an array, but I wanted to know some other solutions to this. Maybe I'm missing some ctypes trick or maybe I simply used resize wrong. The name c_long_Array_0 seems to tell me this may not work with resize.

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> c_int * 0
<class '__main__.c_long_Array_0'>
>>> intType = c_int * 0
>>> foo = intType()
>>> foo
<__main__.c_long_Array_0 object at 0xb7ed9e84>
>>> foo[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: invalid index
>>> resize(foo, sizeof(c_int * 1))
>>> foo[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: invalid index
>>> foo
<__main__.c_long_Array_0 object at 0xb7ed9e84>
>>> sizeof(c_int * 0)
0
>>> sizeof(c_int * 1)
4
```

Edit: Maybe go with something like:

```
>>> ctypes_resize = resize
>>> def resize(arr, type):
...     tmp = type()
...     for i in range(len(arr)):
...         tmp[i] = arr[i]
...     return tmp
...     
... 
>>> listType = c_int * 0
>>> list = listType()
>>> list = resize(list, c_int * 1)
>>> list[0]
0
>>>
```

But that's ugly passing the type instead of the size. It works for its purpose and that's it.

Comment: Scott, I forgot one thing. I think if your array was initialized like we are doing it (without mallocing a block, letting ctypes do it) then you need to keep a reference to the original object in the new ctypes object, because I think the memory is freed when the first object dies. So you will need to do "if hasattr(array,"original"), newarray.original = array.original, else newarray.original = array". Then the garbage collector will trash the original array which in turn frees the block. If you need help just ask in the comments box.

Comment: Gotcha. I ran into a problem where I couldn't resize a _field_ member in a ctypes Structure. Something about the memory not being owned or something. Not a huge deal.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm running into a gc issue: python: Modules/gcmodule.c:241: update_refs: Assertion `gc->gc.gc_refs == (-3)' failed.

Comment: @Scott: You can't resize individual fields because all the memory is taken care of by the main struct object. What you should do is manually allocate the memory by yourself with something like create_buffer and then creating a destructor to free it with a __del__ method. I have never seen that python gc error, how did you get it?

Comment: Yeah, I figured out how to deal with that memory issue. Wasn't too big of a deal. I'm not exactly sure how I got it to throw that error yet. I have a lot of code to dig through. I ported a bunch of C code over to Python, so the problem's within a big haystack. I'll let you know when I find it.

Comment: Ok, I still don't know what was causing it, but changing one class to a regular non-ctypes (non-structure) class fixed it. I know the crash would happen during the program's exit, and the name of the function update_refs seems to suggest something didn't get freed. That's all I can figure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
from ctypes import *

list = (c_int*1)()

def customresize(array, new_size):
    resize(array, sizeof(array._type_)*new_size)
    return (array._type_*new_size).from_address(addressof(array))

list[0] = 123
list = customresize(list, 5)

>>> list[0]
123
>>> list[4]
0
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad I asked. I didn't expect an answer. :)

Comment: I think I am one of the few ctypes experts here. Strangely I only have written a couple of c/python bindings, and have almost no experience with pyrex/boost/regular modules.

Comment: Let me ask you this. Can I use ctypes pointers like C pointers? Like traversing an array of chars with an addition or subtraction?

Comment: Yes. (The notification seems to be broken). intptr = POINTER(c_int)() intptr[0] intptr[234] etc

Comment: I have encountered buffer corruption with this approach. Example: `list = (c_size_t * 1)(42); list2 = customresize(list, 10); print(list2[0]); list = None; print(list2[0])` results in the output `42`, `140255071020176`. I think the problem boils down to `_b_needsfree_` being 1 on both `list` and `list2`, so when `list` is deleted, it frees the buffer that actually belongs to `list2` now. My workaround for now is to create a new array and copy the elements over.