# Resize ctypes array within structure

Tags: arrays, resize, structure, ctypes

I have these C structures and function prototypes within my `libray.dll`. I´m interested in `pvData` field, which will contain an array of data i need to extract by calling the `OnLineGetData` function:

```
typedef struct tagSAFEARRAY {
    void * pvData;              
} SAFEARRAY;

__declspec(dllexport) long OnLineGetData(SAFEARRAY **pData);
```

Then, i load the `library.dll` and create the same structure and function prototype using ctypes:

```
import ctypes

myLibrary = ctypes.CDLL('library.dll')

class tagSAFEARRAY(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("pvData", ctypes.c_int16 * 20 )]

OnLineGetData = myLibrary.OnLineGetData
OnLineGetData.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.POINTER(tagSAFEARRAY)]
OnLineGetData.restype = ctypes.c_long
```

Then, i create a double pointer to the tagSAFEARRAY class, as it is an argument for the OnLineGetData funtion:

```
dataStructure = ctypes.POINTER(tagSAFEARRAY)(tagSAFEARRAY())
```

You'll notice that the pvData field is a 20 short array, it has a fixed size. That's because whenever i try to modify the pvData size i got the same problems as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879609/resize-shrink-a-ctypes-array) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919369/resize-ctypes-array), but none of its solutions worked for me. I need to resize this array because it will contain the exact amount of values i need to extract from the `OnLineGetData` function. If i need to extract 10 values that array size needs to be 10, if a need to extract 27 values i need to resize `pvData` accordingly, and so on.

So, my question is, how could i resize the `pvData` array contained in the `tagSAFEARRAY` structure?

Comment: why not just keep your `void*` pointer (`ctypes.c_void_p`) and then cast it using [`ctypes.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast) to an array with the appropriate number of elements?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you know how long the `pvData` field will be, but the answer is still the same...leave the parameter as a `c_void_p` and cast it to the correct size after return.

For this example I assumed the return value of OnLineGetData returns the number of elements, and cast `pvData` to a pointer of that array size and dereference it.  Below is the C code for demonstration:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct tagSAFEARRAY {
    void * pvData;
} SAFEARRAY;

__declspec(dllexport) long OnLineGetData(SAFEARRAY **pData) {
    *pData = malloc(sizeof(SAFEARRAY));
    short* p = malloc(10 * sizeof(int16_t));
    for(int16_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        p[i] = i;
    (*pData)->pvData = p;
    return 10;
}
```

test.py:

```py
import ctypes as ct

myLibrary = ct.CDLL('./test')

class SAFEARRAY(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = ("pvData", ct.c_void_p),

OnLineGetData = myLibrary.OnLineGetData
OnLineGetData.argtypes = ct.POINTER(ct.POINTER(SAFEARRAY)),
OnLineGetData.restype = ct.c_long

p = ct.POINTER(SAFEARRAY)()
n = OnLineGetData(ct.byref(p))

# p is a void**
# p.contents is a void*
# cast to a pointer to n-element array:
# dereference to get the n-element array
arr = ct.cast(p.contents.pvData,ct.POINTER(ct.c_int16 * n)).contents
print(arr)
print(list(arr))
```

Output:

```
<__main__.c_short_Array_10 object at 0x00000228ED42EF40>
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```